# How to blur UIImage excluding specific point.

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, instagram, gpuimage

In GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter how to set the point of non image blur ? i tried setting the point excludeCirclePoint but everything gets blur. I want to implement touches gesture and the touched point remains good while the other image gets blur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign `CGPoint` to filter's `excludeCirclePoint` property where `CGPointMake(0, 0)` is the top-left corner of the image and `CGPointMake(1, 1)` is the bottom-right corner.

Something like:

```
GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter *filter = [[GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter alloc] init];
filter.excludeCirclePoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5); // center
```